# Calculating first few eigen values of a large Matrix

Tags: numpy, eigenvalue

Is there any way to calculate the first few or last few eigen values of a large matrix, say 6000x6000?

It is taking extremely long to calculate all the eigen values. However, I just need the largest 100 or 200 eigen vectors. Is there any way to do this?

Till now I have used:

```
    eigvalues, eigvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)
```

where A is a large matrix. But I am getting all the eigen values/vectors. Anyway to get a subset of eigenvalues so that I can reduce my computation?

Comment: Look at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html

Comment: Thanks...but it does not give me the first few eigen vectors/values. It just gives me a random subset of the total number of eigen values. In fact, if I want to retain 2 values, it is giving the largest and the smallest eigen values. Any way I can get the k largest ones?

Comment: Did you experiment with the `which` parameter?  But, are eigenvalues inherently ordered?  Wouldn't that depend on the calculation method?